# Template not rendering Django (NoReverseMatch)

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, window.location

I am not exactly sure what the issue is but I have this code in my project that once I select a date it will bring up a table with the name of students in my classroom but Django keeps telling me that there isnt NoReverseMatch. i have double check and everything is fine but not sure why it not working.

**ERROR SHOWN**

Reverse for 'attendance-page' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['attendance/(?P[0-9]+)\Z']

**urls.py**

```
path('attendance_class', views.attendance_class, name='attendance-class'),
    path('attendance/<int:classPK>', views.attendance, name='attendance-page'),
    path(r'attendance/<int:classPK>/<str:date>',views.attendance, name='attendance-page-date'),
    path('save_attendance', views.save_attendance, name='save-attendance'),
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def attendance_class(request):
    classes = Room.objects.all()
    context = {}
    context['classes'] = classes
    return render(request, 'school/attendance_page.html', context)


@login_required
def attendance(request, classPK=None, date=None):
    _class = Room.objects.get(id=classPK)
    students = Student.objects.filter(id__in=ClassStudent.objects.filter(classIns=_class).values_list('student')).all()
    context = {}
    context['class'] = _class
    context['date'] = date
    att_data = {}
    for student in students:
        att_data[student.id] = {}
        att_data[student.id]['data'] = student
    if not date is None:
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        year = date.strftime('%Y')
        month = date.strftime('%m')
        day = date.strftime('%d')
        attendance = Attendance.objects.filter(
            attendance_date__year=year, attendance_date__month=month, attendance_date__day=day, classIns=_class).all()
        for att in attendance:
            att_data[att.student.pk]['type'] = att.type
    print(list(att_data.values()))
    context['att_data'] = list(att_data.values())
    context['students'] = students

    return render(request, 'school/attendance_control.html')


def save_attendance(request):
    resp = {'status': 'failed', 'msg': ''}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        date = datetime.strptime(post['attendance_date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
        year = date.strftime('%Y')
        month = date.strftime('%m')
        day = date.strftime('%d')
        _class = Room.objects.get(id=post['classIns'])
        Attendance.objects.filter(attendance_date__year=year, attendance_date__month=month,
                                  attendance_date__day=day, classIns=_class).delete()
        for student in post.getlist('student[]'):
            type = post['type['+student+']']
            studInstance = Student.objects.get(id=student)
            att = Attendance(student=studInstance, type=type, classIns=_class,
                             attendance_date=post['attendance_date']).save()
        resp['status'] = 'success'
        messages.success(request, "Attendance has been saved successfully.")
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp), content_type="application/json")
```

**Jquery used**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('table td, table th').addClass('px-2 py-1')
        $('#data-form').change(function() {
            location.href = "{% url 'attendance-page' class.pk %}/" + $(this).val()
            
        })
        $('#attendance-form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            var _this = $(this)
            $('.err-msg').remove();
            var el = $('<div>')
            el.addClass("alert alert-danger err-msg")
            el.hide()
            start_loader()
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'save-attendance' %}",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                method: 'POST',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                error: err => {
                    console.log(err)
                    alert("An error occured ", 'error');
                    end_loader();
                },
                success: function (resp) {
                    if (typeof resp == 'object' && resp.status == 'success') {
                        el.removeClass("alert alert-danger err-msg ")
                        location.reload()
                    } else if (resp.status == 'failed' && !!resp.msg) {
                        el.html(resp.msg)
                    } else {
                        el.text("An error occured ", 'error');
                        end_loader();
                        console.err(resp)
                    }
                    _this.prepend(el)
                    el.show('slow')
                    $("html, body, .modal ").scrollTop(0);
                    end_loader()
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

**attendance template**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card card-default rounded-0 shadow ">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="card-title fw-bold">Class Attendance Management</h4>
                <div class="tools">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form id="attendance-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="classIns" value="{{ class.pk }}">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Class Details</legend>
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100">
                                    <div class="col-auto pe-2 text-muted">Department:</div>
                                    <div class="col-auto flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-1">
                                        <p class="m-0 fw-bold">{{ class.assigned_faculty.department }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> -->
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100">
                                    <div class="col-auto pe-2 text-muted">School Year:</div>
                                    <div class="col-auto flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-1">
                                        <p class="m-0 fw-bold">{{ class.school_year }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100">
                                    <div class="col-auto pe-2 text-muted">Level:</div>
                                    <div class="col-auto flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-1">
                                        <p class="m-0 fw-bold">{{ class.level }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100">
                                    <div class="col-auto pe-2 text-muted">Name:</div>
                                    <div class="col-auto flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-1">
                                        <p class="m-0 fw-bold">{{ class.name }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="d-flex w-100">
                                    <div class="col-auto pe-2 text-muted">Faculty:</div>
                                    <div class="col-auto flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-1">
                                        <p class="m-0 fw-bold">{{ class.form_teacher}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <hr>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Date of Class</legend>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <input id="data-form" type="date" name="attendance_date" value="{% if date %}{{ date }}{% endif %}"class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                {% if date %}
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Attendance List</legend>
                    <table class="table tables-bordered" id="student-list">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col width="5%">
                            <col width="25%">
                            <col width="25%">
                            <col width="15%">
                            <col width="15%">
                            <col width="15%">
                        </colgroup>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-ceter">#</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Student Code</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Student Name</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Total Tardy</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Total Absent</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Total Present</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for student in att_data %}
                            <tr class="">
                                <td class="text-center">{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                                <td>{{ student.data.student_code }}</td>
                                <td>{{ student.data.first_name }} {{ student.data.middle_name }} {{ student.data.last_name }}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="student[]" value="{{ student.data.pk }}">
                                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="type[{{ student.data.pk }}]" value="1"
                                        id="btnradio-{{student.data.pk}}" {% if student.type == '1' %} checked="checked" {% endif %}
                                        autocomplete="off" required>
                                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm px-1 py-0" for="btnradio-{{student.data.pk}}"><i
                                            class="fa fa-check  text-light"></i></label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="type[{{ student.data.pk }}]" value="2"
                                        id="btnradio-2-{{ student.data.pk }}" {% if student.type == '2' %} checked="checked" {% endif %}
                                        autocomplete="off">
                                    <label class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm px-1 py-0" for="btnradio-2-{{ student.data.pk }}"><i
                                            class="fa fa-check text-light"></label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="type[{{ student.data.pk }}]" value="3"
                                        id="btnradio-3-{{ student.data.pk }}" {% if student.type == '3' %} checked="checked" {% endif %}
                                        autocomplete="off">
                                    <label class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm px-1 py-0" for="btnradio-3-{{ student.data.pk }}"><i
                                            class="fa fa-check text-light"></label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                        <div class="clear-fix py-3"></div>
                        <center>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0 bg-gradient"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                                Save</button>
                        </center>
                    </fieldset>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's this line `location.href = "{% url 'attendance-page' class.pk %}/" + $(this).val()`
class.pk is not defined so it tries to call url with 0 arguments while it needs only one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, while this answer may solve the OP's problem, but you should also see how do I write a good answer [answer].

Comment: thanks but it was a silly mistake the context wasn't being passs